# How to get issuer of a X509Certificate object by Bouncy Castle in C#

Tags: c#, security, certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate

I have a Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate object in Bouncy Castle class libraries,How can I get the certificate's issuer certificate(or issuer root cert)  and export it ?

cert.CertificateStructure.Issuer is X509Name class,but not X509Certificate class.

In addition, in the.Net framework, I can implement the following code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Name {
    class Class1 {
    public static X509Certificate2 GetIssuer(X509Certificate2 leafCert) {
        if (leafCert.Subject == leafCert.Issuer) { return leafCert; }
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.Build(leafCert);
        X509Certificate2 issuer = null;
        if (chain.ChainElements.Count > 1) {
            issuer = chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate;
        }
        chain.Reset();
        return issuer;
    }
}
}
```